# Rename files using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename

I have a bash script set that executes in a folder containing a number of photos and sequentially stitches them into panoramas based on the user input.  Once the generation is completed, the output file is renamed to `$x-pano.jpg` and moved one folder higher.

My issue is the number prefix is based on the sequential execution of the script, meaning all files get renamed `1-pano.jpg` to `n-pano.jpg` based on the number of panoramas generated during the script execution.

How can I modify the renaming process to look at the storage folder and get the largest `$x`?  I want to increment that number by 1 and use as the file's numerical prefix.  My current code is

```
//get the list of files in directory and sort in increasing order
$filelist=$(find ../ -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -n)

//get number of files
$length=${filelist[@]}

//get the last file
$lastFile=${fileList[$((length-1))]}
```

will get a list of the files, sort in increasing order and get the last file from the list.  This is where I get stuck.  Using `-` as a delimiter, how can I capture the current value?

Comment: No dollar signs on the left side of an assignment. Add a set of parentheses to create an array: `filelist=($(find ../ -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -n))`. To get the count: `length=${#filelist[@]}`. To get the last file: `lastFile=${fileList[@]: -1}` (note that an array subscript is already an arithmetic context so no `$(())` is necessary, but it's not until Bash 4.2 that you can use negative subscripts so you have to use a negative slice in earlier versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`${var%%foo}` construct, which strips the longest `foo` from the end of a variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html):

```
$ F=1-pano.jpg
$ echo ${F%%-pano.jpg}
1
$ F=1222-pano.jpg
$ echo ${F%%-pano.jpg}
1222
```

Try `lastNum=${lastFile%%-pano.jpg}`.

Comment: I ended up going in a different direction, but your answer helped a great dea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is just a renaming task:

```
$ find jason-pics/ -type f
jason-pics/other.jpg
jason-pics/somefile.jpg
jason-pics/mountain.jpg
jason-pics/car.jpg
```

Renaming:

```
i=0 
for jfile in $(find jason-pics/ -type f)
    do 
        echo "Renaming $jfile to jason-pics-rename/$i-pano-$(basename $jfile)" 
        ((i+=1)) 
        cp -v $jfile jason-pics-rename/$i-pano-$(basename $jfile)
done
```

Content of jason-pics-rename directory:

```
$ find jason-pics-rename/ -type f 
jason-pics-rename/4-pano-car.jpg
jason-pics-rename/1-pano-other.jpg
jason-pics-rename/3-pano-mountain.jpg
jason-pics-rename/2-pano-somefile.jpg
```

Removing basename to rename files to 1-pano.jpg to n-pano.jpg

```
$ i=0; for jfile in $(find jason-pics/ -type f); do echo "Renaming $jfile to jason-pics-rename/$i-pano-$(basename $jfile)" ;((i+=1)); cp -v $jfile jason-pics-rename/$i-pano.jpg; done
```

Content is:

```
$ find jason-pics-rename/ -type f 
jason-pics-rename/3-pano.jpg
jason-pics-rename/2-pano.jpg
jason-pics-rename/1-pano.jpg
jason-pics-rename/4-pano.jpg
```