# Script for copying and renaming files (.bin to .pdf) under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a tomcat based document management system on Ubuntu. When you load files into the dms it creates a folder structure and inserts the document with the ending .bin. Normally I will upload only pdf files.

Now I need a script that executes all the time a new document is uploaded (a new .bin file is created). It should copy the .bin file and replace the ending .bin with .pdf in the same directory (the original .bin file must be kept).

The folder structure looks like this:

```
documents/2013/10/03/11/45/48_1380793509616.bin
```

or

```
documents/2013/10/17/17/45/57_1382024759406.bin
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your sticking point the copying of files or the fact that it runs whenever a new file is uploaded?

Comment: It is both. I do not have any experience with linux batch scripting. All the time a new bin file is uploaded it has to be copied and the file extension of the new file has to be renamed from `.bin` to `.pdf`

Comment: There are a lot of elements, then. Do you want to move the file to `pdf` (meaning the script can just act on any `bin` file it finds) or have both copies there (meaning it needs to check if there is a `pdf` for each `bin`. I think it is too broad to give the whole solution here, but you should call it with a `cron` job and it can use a `for` loop to act on a list of files (either specifically by date or searching all subdirectories), copying each file within. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130570/rename-files-using-bash-script) for the file renaming part...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the bash parameter substitution feature to change the extension:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n `file $1 | grep PDF` ]]
then
        cp $1 ${1%.bin}.pdf
fi
```

The example above also verifies that the file is, in fact, a PDF.